# Why doesn't my simple pytorch network work on GPU device?

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I built a simple network from a tutorial and I got this error:

> RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.cuda.FloatTensor but found
>   type torch.FloatTensor for argument #4 'mat1'

Any help? Thank you!

```
import torch
import torchvision

device = torch.device("cuda:0")
root = '.data/'

dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root, transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(), download=True)

dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=4)


class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.out = torch.nn.Linear(28*28, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.out(x)
        return x

net = Net()
net.to(device)

for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(dataloader):
    inputs.to(device)
    out = net(inputs)
```

Comment: This question is about PyTorch, not CUDA. That is why I have removed the tag. Twice. Please don't add it again

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**TL;DR**
This is the fix

```
inputs = inputs.to(device)
```

**Why?!**
There is a slight difference between [`torch.nn.Module.to()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.to) and [`torch.Tensor.to()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.to): while `Module.to()` is an **in-place** operator, `Tensor.to()` is not. Therefore

```
net.to(device)
```

Changes `net` itself and moves it to `device`. On the other hand

```
inputs.to(device)
```

does not change `inputs`, but rather returns a **copy** of `inputs` that resides on `device`. To use that "on device" copy, you need to assign it into a variable, hence

```
inputs = inputs.to(device)
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I spent several hours searching for an answer.

Comment: @Harkonnen glad I could help. When reading pytorch docs you should pay attention to "in-place" operations: some methods are in-place, some are not, and some have an "in-place" variants...

Comment: I had this error because I hadn't set my GPU device, as: device = torch.device('cuda')