# pytorch how to remove cuda() from tensor

Tags: python, type-conversion, pytorch, tensor

I got `TypeError: expected torch.LongTensor (got torch.cuda.FloatTensor)`.

How do I convert `torch.cuda.FloatTensor` to `torch.LongTensor`?

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_v2.py", line 110, in <module>
    main()
  File "train_v2.py", line 81, in main
    model.update(batch)
  File "/home/Desktop/squad_vteam/src/model.py", line 131, in update
    loss_adv = self.adversarial_loss(batch, loss, self.network.lexicon_encoder.embedding.weight, y)
  File "/home/Desktop/squad_vteam/src/model.py", line 94, in adversarial_loss
    adv_embedding = torch.LongTensor(adv_embedding)
TypeError: expected torch.LongTensor (got torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
```

Comment: How do you load or create `model`? It might make sense to make the model and its attributes CPU compatible at load/create time (as opposed to cuda/GPU compatible)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a float tensor `f` and want to convert it to long, you do `long_tensor = f.long()`

You have `cuda` tensor i.e data is on gpu and want to move it to cpu you can do `cuda_tensor.cpu()`.

So to convert a torch.cuda.Float tensor `A` to torch.long do `A.long().cpu()`

Answer (score 4):

Best practice for Pytorch 0.4.0 is to write [device agnostic code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#device-agnostic-code): That is, instead of using `.cuda()` or `.cpu()` you can simply use [`.to(torch.device("cpu"))`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.to)

```
A = A.to(dtype=torch.long, device=torch.device("cpu"))
```

Note that `.to()` is not an "in-place" operation (see, e.g.,  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51606286/1714410)), thus you need to assign `A.to(...)` back into `A`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a tensor `t`.

```
t = t.cpu()
```

would be the old way.

```
t = t.to("cpu")
```

would be the new API.

Comment: Both are valid though in 1.0