# Pytorch embedding RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.LongTensor but found type torch.cuda.LongTensor for argument #3 'index'

Tags: python, typeerror, pytorch, word-embedding

I'm getting this error saying

```
RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.LongTensor but found type torch.cuda.LongTensor for argument #3 'index'
```

But what does it mean by `argument #3 "index"`? I can't find "`index`" argument in `torch.embedding` (here source : https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/sparse.html#Embedding) 
It seems like I'm passing the embedding the wrong parameters.

I even changed the data type of my input like below but the error persists.

```python
batch['doc_tok'] = batch['doc_tok'].long()
batch['query_tok'] = batch['query_tok'].long()
```

Any comment (even though it's short!) or just listing keywords to look at will be highly appreciated!

---

Here is a full traceback.

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_v2.py", line 110, in <module>
    main()
  File "train_v2.py", line 81, in main
    model.update(batch)
  File "/home/aerin/Desktop/squad_vteam/src/model.py", line 129, in update
    loss_adv = self.adversarial_loss(batch, loss, self.network.lexicon_encoder.embedding.weight, y)
  File "/home/aerin/Desktop/squad_vteam/src/model.py", line 104, in adversarial_loss
    start, end, _ = self.network(batch)
  File "/home/aerin/anaconda3/envs/san/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 491, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aerin/Desktop/squad_vteam/src/dreader.py", line 78, in forward
    doc_mask, query_mask = self.lexicon_encoder(batch)
  File "/home/aerin/anaconda3/envs/san/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 491, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aerin/Desktop/squad_vteam/src/encoder.py", line 116, in forward
    doc_emb, query_emb = emb(doc_tok), emb(query_tok)
  File "/home/aerin/anaconda3/envs/san/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 491, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aerin/anaconda3/envs/san/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py", line 108, in forward
    self.norm_type, self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse)
  File "/home/aerin/anaconda3/envs/san/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1076, in embedding
    return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.LongTensor but found type torch.cuda.LongTensor for argument #3 'index'
```

---

Update: I even sent the whole model.network to cpu but still getting the same error.

```
batch['doc_tok']=batch['doc_tok'].long().cpu()
batch['query_tok']=batch['query_tok'].long().cpu()
self.network.cpu()

print(batch['doc_tok'].dtype,  batch['query_tok'].dtype) # They are both torch.int64 torch.int64

start, end, _ = self.network(batch)
```

At this point, I'm suspecting this might be a bug...

model.py code: https://github.com/byorxyz/san_mrc/blob/master/src/model.py

Network defined: https://github.com/byorxyz/san_mrc/blob/master/src/dreader.py

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pytorch how to remove cuda() from tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51664192/pytorch-how-to-remove-cuda-from-tensor)

Comment: @Shai removing cuda() only doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me like your input/target tensors (`batch['doc_tok']`, etc.) and your network and its variables (I believe `index` is an internal tensor for `Embedding` layers) are on different devices (CPU for your data, GPU for your model?).

If you want everything to run on GPU, you need both to:

- Load your data there,  e.g. `batch['doc_tok'].cuda()`
- Load your model there, e.g. `model.network.cuda()`

Same goes if you want to run on CPU, replacing with `.cpu()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment! I even sent the whole model to cpu as you suggested using model.network.cpu(), still getting the same error. At this point I think it's a bug in pytorch.

Comment: Do you happen to know what it means by argument #3 "index"?

Comment: Probably some indexing tensor for the embedding matrix, though I do not know the exact implementation of `Embedding`. Let's hope your question on the pytorch forum gets more success - otherwise maybe try sharing the lines where you build your model? Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for replying! I shared the code on the question as you suggested. (if you ever have time to take a look at ...)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
batch['doc_tok']=batch['doc_tok'].long().cpu()
batch['query_tok']=batch['query_tok'].long().cpu()
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tried but I'm still getting the same error.