# AWS EC2 Deep Learning instance cuda 3.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pytorch, gpu

I just launched (and paid for) the `Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu 18.04) Version 27.0 (ami-0dbb717f493016a1a)` instance type `g2.2xlarge`.  I activated

`for PyTorch with Python3 (CUDA 10.1 and Intel MKL) ____________source activate pytorch_p36`

When I run my pytorch network I see a warning

```
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py:134: UserWarning: 
    Found GPU0 GRID K520 which is of cuda capability 3.0.
    PyTorch no longer supports this GPU because it is too old.
    The minimum cuda capability that we support is 3.5.
```

Is this real?

This is my code to put my neural net on the gpu

```
if torch.cuda.is_available():
        device = torch.device("cuda:0")  # you can continue going on here, like cuda:1 cuda:2....etc. 
        print("Running on the GPU")
    else:
        device = torch.device("cpu")
        print("Running on the CPU")

    net = Net(image_height, image_width)
    net.to(device)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use a `g3s.xlarge` instance.  I guess the g2 instances use older GPUs.

Also I had to make `num_workers=0` on my dataloaders following this https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/oserror-errno-12-cannot-allocate-memory-but-memory-usage-is-actually-normal/56027.

And this is another pytorch gotcha https://stackoverflow.com/a/51606286/3614578 when adding tensors to a device.