# How do i make my PyTorch DCGAN code to run on a GPU?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to train a DCGAN on a GPU but as I am starting out with PyTorch I have tried to do something from the documentation and it works but I want to confirm if it is the correct way to do it as I have done cause I looked at many other questions about running it on the GPU but they are done in different ways.

```
import os
import torch
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.nn import (
    BatchNorm2d,
    BCELoss,
    Conv2d,
    ConvTranspose2d,
    LeakyReLU,
    Module,
    ReLU,
    Sequential,
    Sigmoid,
    Tanh,
)
from torch.optim import Adam
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision.datasets import CIFAR10
from torchvision.utils import save_image
from tqdm import tqdm

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

dataset = DataLoader(
    CIFAR10(
        root="./Data",
        download=True,
        transform=transforms.Compose(
            [
                transforms.Resize(64),
                transforms.ToTensor(),
                transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)),
            ]
        ),
    ),
    batch_size=64,
    shuffle=True,
    num_workers=2,
)

try:
    os.mkdir("./Models")
    os.mkdir("./Results")

except FileExistsError:
    pass


class Gen(Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Gen, self).__init__()
        self.main = Sequential(
            ConvTranspose2d(100, 512, 4, 1, 0, bias=False),
            BatchNorm2d(512),
            ReLU(True),
            ConvTranspose2d(512, 256, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            BatchNorm2d(256),
            ReLU(True),
            ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            BatchNorm2d(128),
            ReLU(True),
            ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            BatchNorm2d(64),
            ReLU(True),
            ConvTranspose2d(64, 3, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            Tanh(),
        )

    def forward(self, input):
        output = self.main(input)
        return output


class Dis(Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dis, self).__init__()
        self.main = Sequential(
            Conv2d(3, 64, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            Conv2d(64, 128, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            BatchNorm2d(128),
            LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            Conv2d(128, 256, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            BatchNorm2d(256),
            LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            Conv2d(256, 512, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            BatchNorm2d(512),
            LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            Conv2d(512, 1, 4, 1, 0, bias=False),
            Sigmoid(),
        )

    def forward(self, input):
        output = self.main(input)
        return output.view(-1)


def weights(obj):
    classname = obj.__class__.__name__
    if classname.find("Conv") != -1:
        obj.weight.data.normal_(0.0, 0.02)

    elif classname.find("BatchNorm") != -1:
        obj.weight.data.normal_(1.0, 0.02)
        obj.bias.data.fill_(0)


gen = Gen()
gen.apply(weights)
gen.cuda().cuda().to(device)

dis = Dis()
dis.apply(weights)
dis.cuda().to(device)

criterion = BCELoss()

optimizerDis = Adam(dis.parameters(), lr=0.0002, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
optimizerGen = Adam(gen.parameters(), lr=0.0002, betas=(0.5, 0.999))

for epoch in range(25):
    for batch, data in enumerate(tqdm(dataset, total=len(dataset)), 0):
        dis.zero_grad()

        input = Variable(data[0]).cuda().to(device)
        target = Variable(torch.ones(input.size()[0])).cuda().to(device)
        output = dis(input).cuda().to(device)

        realError = criterion(output, target)

        noise = Variable(torch.randn(input.size()[0], 100, 1, 1)).cuda().to(device)
        fake = gen(noise).cuda().to(device)
        target = Variable(torch.zeros(input.size()[0])).cuda().to(device)
        output = dis(fake.detach()).cuda().to(device)

        fakeError = criterion(output, target)

        errD = realError + fakeError
        errD.backward()
        optimizerDis.step()

        gen.zero_grad()

        target = Variable(torch.ones(input.size()[0])).cuda().to(device)
        output = dis(fake).cuda().to(device)

        errG = criterion(output, target)
        errG.backward()
        optimizerGen.step()

        print(f"  {epoch+1}/25 Dis Loss: {errD.data:.4f} Gen Loss: {errG.data:.4f}")

save_image(data[0], "./Results/Real.png", normalize=True)
save_image(gen(noise).data, f"./Results/Fake{epoch+1}.png", normalize=True)
torch.save(gen, f"./Models/model{epoch+1}.pth")
```

Comment: so, what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments about your code:

1. What is the value of your `device` variable?
   Make sure is is `torch.device('cuda:0')` (or whatever you GPU's device id is).
   Otherwise, if your `device` is actually `torch.device('cpu')` then you run in CPU.
   See [`torch.device`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_attributes.html#torch.torch.device) for more information.
2. You removed the "model" part of your code, but you may have skipped an important part there: Have you moved your model to GPU as well? Usually a model contains many internal parameters (aka trainable weights) and you need them also on device.
   your code should also have

```py
dis.to(device)
criterion.to(device)  # if your loss function also has trainable parameters
```

Note that unlike `torch.tensor`s, calling `.to` on a `nn.Module` is [an "in place" operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51606286/1714410).

3. You have redundancy in your code: you do not have to call *both* [`.cuda()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.cuda) AND [`.to()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.to).
   Calling `.cuda()` was the old way of moving things to GPU, but for a while now pytorch introduced `.to()` to make coding simpler.
4. Since both your inputs, and model are on GPU, you do not need to explicitly move the outputs to device as well. Thus, you can replace `output = dis(input).cuda().to(device)` with just `output = dis(input)`.
5. No need to use `Variable` explicitly. You can replace

```py
noise = Variable(torch.randn(input.size()[0], 100, 1, 1)).cuda().to(device)
```

with

```py
noise = torch.randn(input.size()[0], 100, 1, 1), device=input.device)
```

You can also use [`torch.zeros_like`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.zeros_like) and [`torch.ones_like`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.ones_like) for the `target` variable:

```py
target = torch.zeros_like(input)
```

Note that `zeros_like` and `one_like` take care for the device (and data type) for you - it will be the same as `input`'s.

Comment: Yes, the value id torch.device("cuda:0") and yes I have moved te models to GPU in the same way and thanks for telling me these other things about PyTorch as is am just learning it and moved from TensorFlow recently.

Comment: I have one more question as you have said that I should remove the Variable(...) should I remove it from all the places in my code or just the one you told and I have added back the whole code if you want to take a look and thanks for the help.